# delete lines from text file (line after line)

Tags: python

**I have this code to delete lines but the problem when the script comes to sleep after delete one line I found out the text file empty!!**

```py
my_file= open('test.txt', 'r+')
lines = my_file.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
del lines[0]
my_file.seek(0)
my_file.truncate()
my_file.writelines(lines)
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I formatted your question to have Pythonic syntax highlighting and so the code was not double-spaced, but I'm not going to assume which lines are in which blocks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. i.e. some initial file, the exact code execution, the state of the file in the end and what you expected it to be

Comment: Your code doesn't close the file after writing to it. That is the second thing to fix (after the indentation).

Answer (score 0):

#it will delete line number 5th from file.
sed -e '5' filename